# How to get first child to work with JSS-Nested

Tags: reactjs, jss

I am using the jss preset default and it comes with jss-nested.

I could get '&:hover' to work but '&:first-child' does not work for me.

sample code:

```
    summaryItem: {
    borderLeft: '2px solid red',
    '&:first-child': {
        borderLeft: '2px solid transparent',
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You need to add a space for calling child selectors else it would be like calling `div:first-child` instead of `div > :first-child`

```js
    summaryItem: {
    borderLeft: '2px solid red',
    '& > :first-child': {
        borderLeft: '2px solid transparent',
      }
    }
```