# How to override default style with ReactJSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, jss

I've implemented a table in my component:

```
  <table className={classes.vehicleStatusTable}>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>MILEAGE</th>
        <th>TREAD <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye}/></th>
        <th>PRESSURE <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEye}/></th>
        <th>CLEAN</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><span className={classes.unknown}>Unknown</span></td>
        <td><HealthDot value={0} healthRange={null} size='large' /></td>
        <td><HealthDot value={0} healthRange={null} size='large' /></td>
        <td><HealthDot value={0} healthRange={null} size='large' /></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here's the applicable style in my styles file:

```
  vehicleStatusTable: {
    width: '600px',
    '& thead': {
      '& tr': {
        '& th': {
          fontWeight: 'normal',
          textAlign: 'center'
        }
      }
    },
    '& tbody': {
      '& tr': {
        '& td': {
          textAlign: 'center'
        }
      }
    }    
  }
```

The 'center' alignment is appropriate for all of the columns except for the first one.

I've tried several different things to force the first column's alignment to be `left` but none work.  Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add a class to every first element of first column ?

or try using [CSS :nth-child() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

Using a formula (an + b). Description: a represents a cycle size, n is a counter (starts at 0), and b is an offset value.

Here, we specify a background color for all p elements whose index is a multiple of 3:

```
p:nth-child(3n+0) {
  background: red;
}
```

you can see how people are using such selectors in these stackoverflow questions and answers

[How to use pseudo selectors in material-ui?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47024404/how-to-use-pseudo-selectors-in-material-ui)

[How to get first child to work with JSS-Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470478/how-to-get-first-child-to-work-with-jss-nested)

Answer (score 0):

The solution turns out to be quite simple.  Here's an example:

```
<td style={{textAlign: 'left'}}
```